# Global name is not defined

Tags: python

I am trying to check for where a global file has been defined or not.

```
import os, sys, logging...

global my_logger

def init():
  if my_logger is None:
     print 'Logger needs to be initialized'
```

However, when I run this, I get the error:

```
NameError: global name 'my_logger' is not defined
```

Isn't there a way to check if a variable has been declared or no? Do I have to initialize global variables before I can run a check?

Comment: if you're using `global`, you're most likely doing it wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not using the `global` keyword correctly, look up some documentation concerning that.

As a general rule, however, you can test whether a global variable is defined like so:

```
defined = 'my_logger' in globals()
if defined:
    print('my_logger has not been defined')
```

Answer (score 6):

As the other answers stated, the global keyword is needed on access of a global variable, not at the declaration. One should note that you only need to declare a variable as `global` if you plan to assign anything to it - you can read variables from higher scopes without using the global keyword:

```
my_logger = None

def init_logger():
    #needs to use global because we assign to the variable
    global my_logger
    my_logger = MyLogger()

def someOtherFunction():
    #no need to use global as we only access the logger
    if my_logger:
        my_logger.info("i can has logger")
    else:
        print 'logger not initialized'
```

Answer (score 3):

You use the `global` keyword when you need to reference a global variable, not when you define it:

```
import os, sys, logging...

my_logger = None

def init():
  global my_logger
  if my_logger is None:
     print 'Logger needs to be initialized'
```

Comment: Note that this code would work equally well without the `global my_logger` line, though, because my_logger isn't modified.

Comment: And actually, you don't need it to access global variables, only to modify them.